# Properties and ref return values in D

Tags: properties, ref, d

Testing the following in D

```
import std.stdio;

struct S
{
    int _val;
    @property ref int val() { return _val; }
    @property void val(int v) { _val = v; writeln("Setter called!"); }
}

void main()
{
    auto s = S();
    s.val = 5;
}
```

yields `"Settter called!"` as the output.

What rule does the compiler use to determine whether to call the first or the second implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are providing two `@property` methods, one accepts an argument, the other does not. When doing `s.val = 5;`, what you're actually doing is `s.val(5)`, but as `val` is a `@property` you can write it as a property rather than a method call (see http://d-programming-language.org/function.html#property-functions). From `s.val(5)` the compiler can do standard overload resolution - see http://d-programming-language.org/function.html#function-overloading.

Comment: True, but his first @property method returns a `ref int`, so the compiler could also do something like `auto a = val(); a = 5`. It actually **does** that with **dmd v2.054** with the original code - the first implementation is called. And if you switch the lines with the implementations in the source file, the setter is called... So it seems currently dmd simply calls the first implementation in the source file.